# 1-10 volt analog signal

Tags: esp8266, power, pwm

I have an Arduino project where I am using an ESP8266 (Wemos D1 mini) powered via USB. I want/need to output an analog voltage from 0 to 10V.

**Goal:**
A solution that is pre-made (eg a shield or sparkfun type module) or easy to build circuit that does not require a new power supply (besides the ones I have which is 3.3V and 5V, thanks to Wemos USB power).

Many devices allow you to control them using a 1-10V signal. I have two LED drivers at home that I would like to interface with: [specs1](http://www.hidealite.se/Archive/FilesArchive/IM00259_JollyRound350_700mA_several_201706.pdf), [specs2](http://www.hidealite.uk/Archive/FilesArchive/IM00128_MDR_45_60_sv_en_fi_201601.pdf).

What would be the easiest solution to generate a 1-10 Volt signal? Is there a module I can use?

I read about Op-amps but I don't yet have the knowledge to build one myself.
Another method is a DAC, but that seems to require a separate 10 Volt power supply.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please let me know so I can improve the question

Comment: **Seriously!** My question might have issues, but downvoting without leaving an explanation is to say the least not constructive. This gives me a sour taste as a new user. My only option now is to leave as I am clearly not welcome here for reasons unknown to me,

Comment: Welcome to Arduino:SE. I'm not one of those who downvoted, but the question does look to be off-topic here.  There is a good guide on [How to ask a good question for Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2523/33608) on our meta site.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I did vote to close, unfortunately. This would be better asked on SE.Electronics as it isn't really Arduino specific (unless I am missing something)

Comment: @Greenonline, the question is here, so we can answer, how to do it with Arduino. my answer is on-topic, I think

Comment: But @Juraj, whilst your answer seems to be a good answer, it doesn't really mention Arduino (apart from your link), and it seems to be an electronics interfacing question & answer, rather than Arduino specific. I'll cast a reopen vote though

Comment: This question in my opinion exists in the grey area between Arduino and Electronics Stack Exchange.  I think if your question included more mentions of "Arduino" and/or "Arduino project" I think it may have been OK. On the other hand, there is no other way to generate a voltage of 1-10V without using external electronics. The question would then be what circuit is best suited for your situation. With all that said, the majority of Arduino projects need some electronics - just look at the examples and most of them give a circuit to use. I think this would be useful for other Arduino users.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need a DAC. In this 'regulation cases' PWM on digitalPin is used. See [analogWrite](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/) Arduino function.

I use Grove MOSFET module to have PWM of desired voltage. The MCU generates a 3.3 V PWM. MOSFET module gets in my case 5 V as input voltage. You would use 10 V as Vin. MOSFET switches the 10 V line on and off at 'PWM speed' resulting in 10 V PWM.

As 10 V source you could use [a 'boost' converter](https://www.elecrow.com/boost-and-buck-voltage-converter-lm2577-lm2596-p-1254.html), to convert 5 V to 10 V.

This is the schema of the Grove MOSFET module:

[image]

Comment: i would add a cap to the output to filter the PWM into a steady voltage.

Answer (score 3):

The ADM660, link below,

> is a charge-pump voltage converter that can be used to either invert the input supply voltage giving VOUT = -VIN or double it (ADM660 only) giving VOUT = 2 x VIN.

It accepts an input range between 1.5V-7V so if you use the 5V from the Wemos USB power you'll be able to reach the desired 10V for your application, and it's cheap :)

http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADM660_8660.pdf